# Unable to view mounted directories in a chroot

Tags: linux, mount, chroot, bind

Here is a quick description of what I have done:

I have a chrooted user (username: clientdev) which I have jailed inside their home directory. This chroot directory is /home/clientdev/ which is owned by root.

Now I need this clientdev user to be able access the tomcat web application folder which is residing under /mnt/datadrive/tomcat/webapps.

What I have done is :

1. chroot the user with a public key of their own to the home
   directory.
2. Create a folder under /home/clientdev called tomcat_ROOT and gave
   the ownership to clientdev.

Now when I run the command :

```
mount --bind /mnt/datadrive/tomcat/webapps /home/clientdev/tomcat_ROOT
```

The folder disappears from the directory listing inside `/home/clientdev` if I login with clientdev. My root user can see it but not the desired user.

Output of `ls -l /home/clientdev/tomcat_ROOT`:

```
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root   root    4096 Apr 11 15:07 .   
drwxrwxr-x. 12 root   root    4096 Apr 11 15:07 .. 
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root   root    4096 Apr  9 22:10 webapp1 
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root   root    4096 Mar 18 18:43 webapp2 
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root   root    4096 Apr  9 22:11 webapp3 
drwxrwxr-x. 10 root   root    4096 Apr 11 15:20 ROOT
```

Output of `ls -l /home/clientdev/`:

```
drwx------. 4 clientdev clientdev 4096 Apr 10 21:36 . 
drwxr-xr-x. 7 root      root      4096 Apr 10 22:07 .. 
-rw-------. 1 clientdev clientdev  664 Apr 10 21:43 .bash_history 
-rw-r--r--. 1 clientdev clientdev   18 Apr 23  2012 .bash_logout 
-rw-r--r--. 1 clientdev clientdev  176 Apr 23  2012 .bash_profile 
-rw-r--r--. 1 clientdev clientdev  124 Apr 23  2012 .bashrc 
drwx------. 2 clientdev clientdev 4096 Apr 10 19:20 .ssh
drwxr-xr-x. 2 clientdev clientdev 4096 Apr 10 21:34 tomcat_ROOT
```

***The issue I am having is that when the jailed user uses winscp to connect the the server, they are not able to view the mounted folders.***

Comment: Did you restart SSH after it, also are you sure that your client is not caching the directory listing? Some SFTP clients to so make sure to hit Refresh. Your setup seems valid and should work.
Also, you should have just posted with same content as in StackOverflow, as now some of the information is in one question, and some is in another.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I took a look at the caching options in WINSCP and I don't believe that is where the issue is.I also edited the post so that it is more descriptive.

Comment: Did you really run `mount -bind` and not `mount --bind`? Always copy-paste commands and their output.

Comment: What Linux distribution is this on? Does it use a security framework (e.g. SELinux, Apparmor, …)?

Comment: The distro is RHEL 4.4.7 with SELinux set to ENFORCING. That is all that it is configured with at the moment.

Comment: Cross posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044236/chroot-allowing-outside-access-to-chrooted-users-with-mount-bind